# Django href repeats URL in searchbar

Tags: django, django-urls

This is a really basic question but I'm relatively new to django.

I have a navigation bar:

```
<nav>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="transfer"> Home </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="transfer/upload"> Upload </a> </li>
            <li> <a href="transfer/download"> Download </a> </li>
          </ul>
    </nav>
```

So for example when I am at my localhost:8000/transfer and click the "upload" button, I get redirected successfully to localhost:8000/transfer/upload, but afteer that when I click "home" for example, I'm redirected to localhost:8000/transfer/transfer (if I click download from upload, it is localhost:8000/transfer/transfer/download). I've tried modifying my hrefs to not include "transfer/" but then I run into an invalid page when I click a button the first time.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('/upload', views.upload, name='upload'),
    path('/download', views.download, name='download')
]
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Don't delete questions by editing them. By leaving you question up you might help others with similar issues. Instead, mark one of the answers below as "correct" by checking the checkmark to their left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do *not* prepend the urls with a slash, then this is a *relative url*, and then indeed the path is appended to the current path. You can thus prepend the urls with a slash:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="/transfer"> Home </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/transfer/upload"> Upload </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="/transfer/download"> Download </a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But this is one of *the* reasons why it is better to make use of the [**`{% url … }`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) this tag is given the *name* of the view, and will translate this in the corresponding url:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="{% url 'index' %}"> Home </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="{% url 'upload' %}"> Upload </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="{% url 'download' %}"> Download </a> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use absolute path like `localhost:8000/transfer` or like `transfer` (without slash).